# expected value for squared sum of uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

$X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d distributed with $X_1 \sim U(0,\theta), \theta > 0$, how does one get the expected value for $Y = (\sum X_i)^2$? For those types of questions I normally use the linearity of the expected value, especially $E(XY) = EXEY$ if the expected values are independend, but $X_i$ is not independend from $X_i$ thats why I can't use it here right?

Comment: Variance of a sum of independent r.v's is the sum of the variances.

Comment: Ahh thanks alot, so I just need E(Y) and var(Y) and then use var(Y) = E(Y^2) - E(Y)^2 and solve for E(Y^2) right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: thank you that helped a lot

Comment: Just expand out and calculate the sum that way. $E(\sum U_i)^2 = \sum_{i,j} EU_iU_j = n \frac{\theta^2}{3} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} (\frac{\theta}{2})^2$